# Problem in system update; failed install and removal of software packages

Tags: software-center, package-management

I can not install and uninstall software
I used these comments:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

What shall I do ?

Pictures of my errors:

[image: error message dialog]

[image: dpkg error in terminal]

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) might give you some insight.

Answer (score 3):

Package `gdk-pixbuf-psd` wants to put a file in directory `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loader-files.d` but there is no such directory.
I suggest you create it with the command `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loader-files.d` and then try `sudo apt-get autoremove` again.
If this fixes your problem please consider filing a bug report for that package.